# XML Character encoding to HTML

Tags: c#, jquery, html, sql, xml

I am generating XML/HTML from my SQL Query to be placed in my frontend.

The problem is that the conversion from SQL > XML > HTML is not the same encoding.

Each html tag generated by SQL has a class so I want convert the encoding to display correctly in my front using **jQuery**.

*Is there any good jQuery/Javascript function I can use to convert my generated html?*

**Example**

```
é
```

Will convert to:

```
ã©
```

And I want to convert it back to it's normal state.

**SQL Example:** This is how I get my XML/HTML from SQL in my *SELECT Clause, column*

```
htmlForFront = (SELECT ', ' + columnName + '' FROM tableName FOR XML path(''), elements)
```

**NOTE:**

It would be easier for me to implement if it's client side (`jQuery`). But if I have no other choice `C#` would be fine.

Comment: Does it have to be on client side? How are you retrieving the data from where?

Comment: It would be easier for me to implement if it's client side (jQuery). But if I have no other choice C# would be fine.

Comment: What encoding are you using? How are you converting it? Where does it get mangled? It just looks like at some point a UTF-8 sequence is misinterpreted as Latin1. This can happen at any step along the conversion chain down to the display encoding chosen in the browser...

Comment: see my updated question for my select column sql code.

Comment: between your database and UI ensure that any data conversion/handling is done using a more inclusive encoding. "iso-8859-1" is a good candidate here. That includes xsl/xslt files, xml files, readers (like StreamReader) if you are using any. I wouldn't expect UI to be picky.

Answer (score 0):

ASSUMING the query as-is is drawing data, you can ensure the data is handled using "iso-8859-1" encoding by doing something like:

```
htmlForFront = (SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>' + (SELECT ', ' + columnName + '' FROM tableName FOR XML path(''), elements))
```

That way, it will get to the UI intact.

Comment: I implemented your extension, but did not work. any other suggestions?